# Websites become slow whenever cpu goes above 40%

Tags: amazon-ec2, php-fpm

I have an EC2 instance running on c5.4xlarge.

The EC2 instance is running a WordPress multisite that has 42 production sites. We are using Apache webserver. The MySql database is running on the RDS (instance type: db.m5.xlarge).

Whenever EC2 consumes more than 40% Or RDS consumes more than 30%, all our sites become terribly slow and unusable.

There is no database query lock at the time when all our sites become slow. Just the usual increase in network traffic at the business hours.

When the CPU and rds go above 40% and 30%, only the CPU consumption of the "php-fpm" increases. All other processes including httpd consume average CPU power.

At the time of that slowness, I run "SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST" command multiple times. The number of queries increases but none of the queries remain in hang state in between 2 consecutive runs of the above-mentioned command.

Here is my php-fpm configuration :

```
pm = ondemand
pm.max_children = 10
pm.max_requests = 30
pm.max_spare_servers = 5
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.process_idle_timeout = 10
pm.start_servers = 0
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your issue there is no mention of memory stats generally word press is more memory intensive CMS. kindly Look into memory side of things as well.

Comment: Additional information request. 
RDS instance type (you have 2 different types listed in question - please edit), any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.   The URL listed in your profile is not accessible today.